# what does a native speaker say when he wanted to leave his work?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

If someone, who is a medical doctor says that he's leaving his current company, I mean the hospital that he works for, is that something that a native speaker would say?
I'm leaving my hospital?

What else to say also would be possible?

I quit my hospital?
I will knock off the hospital that I work?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be noted that many physicians in the English-speaking world are not employees of the hospitals (or similar institutions) in which they work. The terminology that is appropriate for employees may not be appropriate for them.

Comment: When you say "a native speaker", which country are you talking about? Native speakers in the UK may use different terminology from natives speakers in the US; who may in turn use different terminology from natives speakers in India; ...

Comment: The generic terminology would be "I will resign my position", though there may be other terms, depending on the legalistic circumstances.

Comment: I'm leaving my job, *x* will be my last day working here, I'm not going to be working here [past *date*], my position here will be ending, etc.  Is this because of a rotation?  Change in family circumstances?  Unhappiness on the doctor's part with the hospital?  Unhappiness with the doctor's performance?  The position was for a fixed period, and that period will be ending?  Why do other people need to be informed?  The exact situation would help one choose among many options.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say, "I quit my hospital?" I would say 'I quit my job', 'I'm leaving my job'.  To be more descriptive I would say, 'I quit my job at the hospital' or 'I quit my hospital job'.  Leaving could replace quit in these examples as well.

To me saying "knock off" sounds like one is leaving for the day.  I'll knock off for the night.

[2. verb, slang To stop doing whatever one is doing. Often used as an imperative. In this usage, a noun or pronoun can be used between "knock" and "off," especially in the common phrase "knock it off." Knock it off, you two! I don't want to see any more fighting. I'm going to go tell those kids to knock off all the shouting.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/knock+off)

Comment: In Br English at least "knock off the hospital" sounds as though he's going to steal it, or (possibly) to steal from it.

Comment: The doctor is likely to say something like: "As of D-Date, I will be at Hospital Y."  She may or may not still have privileges at Hospital X and would add that information.

Comment: “I’m resigning from . . . “ is what you might hear in AmE.

Comment: Meanwhile in American English, I wouldn't use "knock off" for any of these things -- I only recognize it as slang for reducing a price, as in, "I'll knock off a few dollars", or in rarer cases maybe reducing other things, e.g. "knock off a few pounds" meaning to lose weight.

Comment: @GlennWillen - In my AmE experience I'm well acquainted with "knocking off for the day" "knocking off a jewelry store" (not really:-)) and "telling the kids to "knock it off".  And also "knocking off a few dollars because of reasons"

Answer (score 0):

In the right context, you really can say "I am leaving the hospital." If you are at lunch with some coworkers at the hospital and you say that, they will know that you aren't a patient being discharged, and they will know because you are in the middle of lunch that you aren't just stepping out for an errand.

And if you use the name of the institution, instead of a generic description, it is even more clear that you are quitting your job. If you work at Smith Memorial Hospital and say "I am leaving Smith Memorial," that generally means that you are quitting your job there. Sometimes people will phrase it this way because "quitting" can have a somewhat negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on context, but the most concise and neutral way to say you are leaving your job is to use the word "resigned." Such as, "I am resigning from the hospital." And, "I have resigned from the hospital."

Answer (score 0):

"I am unable to work here any longer"
"I have to leave my job"
"I can no longer work for this hospital"

Using slang ("knock off") would be inappropriate in a professional business environment like a hospital. Using unprofessional language would imply that you do not take the job seriously or mean disrespect. In a business professional environment it would be expected that the speaker would be giving notice before actually quitting, often two weeks or more, so that might be important to say explicitly.

e.g. "I need to give my two weeks' notice, I am leaving to work elsewhere."